# Running a python program from php and getting output

Tags: php, python

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /Users/thomasbruflot/Documents/nettsider/Curling/Auto.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

I have tried the code above to get a variable called "lenke" from a python script. What I don't understand is how I am supposed to send the variable from the python script. This is how it looks currently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pyimgur
import urllib.request as urllib2

f = open("/Users/thomasbruflot/Documents/nettsider/Curling/test.csv")

data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')

data.remove(data[len(data)-1])
listexy = [data[i].split(',') for i in range(0,len(data))]

listex =[float(i[0]) for i in listexy]
listey = [float(i[1]) for i in listexy]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.plot(listex,listey)
plt.title('Ditt støt')

fig.savefig('DetFunker.png')

CLIENT_ID = "2043cba6776e29d"
PATH = "/Users/thomasbruflot/Documents/nettsider/Curling/DetFunker.png"

im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(PATH, title="Uploaded with PyImgur")
print(uploaded_image.title)
print(uploaded_image.link) 

lenke = uploaded_image.link


req = urllib2.Request(url='http://localhost:8888/Curling/AutoPHP.php?lenke=%s' % uploaded_image.link )
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that python3 was looking for the wrong path in sys. What made it work for me was overwriting it all by adding at the top of my script:

'''
import sys
sys.path = *correct path*
'''
Very funky solution as I don't think one should have to overwrite the path (time-consuming and unnecessary).